# Thermodynamic System, link between state variable, state function, property and characteristics

Tags: thermodynamics, complex-systems

Until now I imagine the whole thing like this:

- The set of necessary [independent state variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_variable#Examples) spans the [state space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation), i.e. my thermodynamic system.
- However, a state function can also be a state variable.

The [wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Thermodynamic_state#/State_variables_and_state_functions) article (on state variables and state functions) is unfortunately a little confusing in my opinion:

> The primary or original identification of the thermodynamic state of a body of matter is by directly measurable ordinary physical quantities.

> Besides the directly measurable ordinary physical variables that originally identify a thermodynamic state of a system, the system is characterized by further quantities called state functions, which are also called state variables, thermodynamic variables, state quantities, or functions of state.

> Thermodynamic temperature is a specifically thermodynamic concept, while the original directly measurable state variables are defined by ordinary physical measurements, without reference to thermodynamic concepts; for this reason, it is helpful to regard thermodynamic temperature as a state function.

So, temperature for example, is not an ordinary physical measurand? That seems to me to be wrong somehow.

And so, somehow state functions and state variables are combined here, is that right? The minimum of necessary state variables/(functions) to describe a thermodynamic system completely is determined by the [Gibbs phase rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_rule):

$$F=K+2-P; \ \ \ F:= \ degrees \ of \ freedom, \ \ \  K:= \ component, \ \ P:= \ phases$$

So for a pure gas, only 2 state variables are needed to derive all other properties/characteristics/state variables/state functions?

So, by specifying 2 of any of these properties of this system, I can derive all the others? That seems a little impossible to me, how the hell do you get to the [specific heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) for example only by specifying volume and [specific volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume)?

[image: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_thermodynamic_properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermodynamic temperature $T$ is defined as the partial differential quotient of system entropy with respect to the internal energy:

$$\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial U} \ ,$$

neither parameter $U$ nor $S$ is a directly measurable quantity. Instead we measure a mechanical/electrical/magnetic/etc. effect of $T$ on, say length, that is directly dependent on said temperature while *other* mechanical/electrical/mechanical/etc., parameters are kept constant.

Comment: Thanks! But how can it be that when I Google for "ordinary physical measurements/-quantity" everywhere the temperature is listed as well? Wouldn't that be wrong?

Comment: a mercury thermometer is thin and long (relative to its thickness) whose variation in length is nearly proportional to its variation in temperature over a reasonably wide range while other physical parameters is kept essentially constant (e.g., pressure). Its length is the measured parameter not its "temperature", we associate the length to its temperature.